# Application Role - Reset Password using hash or Encryption form

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019, role, password, hashing

I need to automate reset password of database application role. Password must be encrypted or hash form due to security reason.

I tried to convert password in hash form using 'Hashbytes' as mentioned below but didn't work.

```
SELECT HASHBYTES('SHA2_256','PASSWORD')
GO
USE <DATABASE NAME>
GO
ALTER APPLICATION ROLE [approle_name] WITH PASSWORD= 'password hash value'
GO
```

I have investigated around password reset of application role but no much able to find out

Are you able to help how can I achievement it or is it possible to do so?

Thanks in Advance
sonny

Comment: Which database system and version?

Comment: It is for SQL Server 2019.